# How to run a specific Javascript function using python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a Javascript file with 2 functions e.g.

```
function function1(){
console.log("Hello world")
}

function function2(){
console.log("Hello world number 2")
}
```

And I want to have a python function which executes either one of these function, how would I do this? BTW I want to do this as I will make one of my python scripts run and generate a value and I want to use Javascript to display this value onto the HTML file fancily.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via setting up Python's backend - then you can render frontend using proper HTML files with specified JS functionality.

#### You could use **Flask** in order to handle the backend in Python:

*(remember to install flask before you use it `pip3 install flask`)*

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder= "/templates")

@app.route('/function1')
def function1():
    return render_template('function1.html')

@app.route('/function2')
def function2():
    return render_template('function2.html')

app.run(port = 8000)
```

*(The templates folder contains different websites you want to display - the ones with your JS functionalities)*

Now when you open your browser with `localhost:8000/function1` You should see your website showing evaluated `function1` value

Comment: I am currently using django is there a similar method for that?

Comment: You might want to read more about _Django REST API_ 
Here is a link to some [Beginner's Guide](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/django-rest-api-tutorial/) on how to do it that I found randomly on the web